# How to prove the limits about integral.

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f (x)$ be continuous on $[0,a](0<a<\pi)$.prove that
$$\lim_{\lambda\to+\infty}\frac{1}{\lambda}\int_{0}^{a}f(x)\frac{\sin^2\lambda x}{\sin^2x}\mathrm{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2}f(0).$$
I thought about splitting $[0, a]$ into $[0, \delta]$, $[\delta, a]$.But it can't go on anymore...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}dy=\pi/2$, the function $g(x)=f(x)\frac{x^2}{\sin ^2 x}$ which is bounded and continuous on $[0,a]$, and the change of variable $y=\lambda x,$ the integral becomes
$$\int_0^{\lambda a}g(y/\lambda)\frac{\sin^2 y}{y^2}dy$$  which tends to $g(0)\pi/2=f(0)\pi/2$ by dominated convergence.